# Remove an element from a list in Common Lisp?

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I am currently trying to remove any NIL I find from a list (recursively) on all levels. I already know how to remove NIL from the top level of a list, and I thought much of the idea would be the same when dealing with multiple levels, however, I have run into a snag.

My code for removing Nil from the top level:

```
(defun removeNILTop (L)
    (cond ( (NULL L) NIL) ;;list is empty
          ( (NULL (CAR L)) (removeNILTop( CDR L))) ;;Nil so skip it
          ( T (CONS( CAR L) (removeNILTop( CDR L)))) ;;not NIL so include it
    )
)
```

This my code for removing Nil from all levels:

```
  (defun removeAll (l)
        (cond
            ((null l) NIL) ;;empty list
            ((null (car l)) (removeAll(cdr l))) ;;Nil so skip it
            ((atom (car l)) (cons (car l) (removeAll(cdr l)))) ;;not nil and is a atom so continue normally
            (T (cons( removeAll(car l) (removeAll(cdr l))))) ;;car is a list recurse into it
        )

    )
```

The way I was thinking about this is that in the first example I ignore what the car of the list and just keep it as long as it's not null. However, now that I care about it, I should check if the car is

- an atom and not nil, if it is then I can proceed normally
- otherwise, if it is a list then I should recurse into it, and cons the result to the result of the cdr.

This obviously is however not working, any tips?

Comment: Did you mean "recurse a list" ... 'cause this has little to do with reversing a list.

Comment: Hey I'm sure you can find an editor to your taste here: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/editor-support.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three cases regarding the `car` now.  Looking at it from the perspective of the current cell:

- The `car` of the current cell is `nil`
- The `car` of the current cell is an atom (and not null)
- The `car` of the current cell is a list

Regarding the `cdr`, assuming nested proper lists, it will always be either a cons cell or `nil`.

You need to recurse on possibly both `car` and `cdr` when they are conses.

Regarding naming: standard behaviour of the Lisp reader is to upcase everything, so the names you are showing are actually `REMOVENILTOP` and `REMOVEALL`.  The convention is to write lower case names with parts separated by dashes: `remove-nil-top`, `remove-all`.  I like the names `remove-nil` and `tree-remove-nil` better, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun removeAll (l)
  (cond ((null l) NIL)
        ((null (car l)) (removeAll(cdr l))) 
        ((atom (car l)) (cons (car l) (removeAll (cdr l)))) 
        (T (cons (removeAll (car l)) (removeAll (cdr l))))))
```

You forgot to close in the last claus the first `removeAll` on `(car l)` with a paranthesis.

You can avoid such mistakes by using an editor which supports paranthesis automatic filling. And indents the code automatically. What editor you use?